# Google Content Experiment with Single page application

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

Is it possible to use Google Content Experiment A/B Testing in my single page application ?

I chose pages website.com#/register and website.com#/register2 but google add ...website.com#/register#utmxid= in preview, so with 2 anchor, can't work.

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Content Experiments JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/experiments#cxjs).

Comment: [New version library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/experiments)